# Is Rectangle A = Rectangle(3, 4); equivalent to Rectangle A(3,4);?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, assignment-operator

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
  int width, height;
 public:
  Rectangle(int, int);
  int area() { return (width * height); }
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(int a, int b) {

  width = a;
  height = b;
}

int main() {
  Rectangle A(3, 4);
  Rectangle B = Rectange(3,4);
  return 0;
}
```

I didn't define any copy constructors or assignment operator for `Rectangle` class.

Is it true that `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3, 4);` actually does three things in serial?

1. Allocate memory space for a temporary variable (let's use `tmp` to denote it) of Rectangle, call `Rectangle::Rectangle(3, 4)` to intialize it.
2. Allocate memory space for variable `B`, initialize it with the default constructor
3. (memberwise) Copy `tmp` to `B` with the assignment operator `Rectangle& operator = (const Rectangle &)`

Does that explanation make sense? I think I might understand wrongly because this process looks very clumsy and inefficient compared with `Rectangle A(3, 4);`.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Is it true that `Rectangle A(3,4)` is equivalent to `Rectangle A = Rectangle(3, 4);`? Thanks!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for the correction! I mixed up with Java syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rectangle A(3, 4);` always simply invokes the `Rectangle(int, int)` constructor, throughout all of the history of C++ having constructors. Simple. Boring.

Now for the fun part.

#### C++17

In the newest (as of this writing) edition of the standard, `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3,4);` immediately collapses down into `Rectangle B(3,4);` This happens regardless of what the nature of `Rectangle`'s move or copy constructors is. This feature is commonly referred to as guaranteed copy elision, although it's important to stress that there is no copy and no move here. What happens is `B` is direct-initialized from `(3,4)`.

#### pre-C++17

Before C++17, there is a temporary `Rectangle` constructed that a compiler may optimize away (and by may, I mean it will certainly, unless you tell it not to). But your ordering of events is not correct. It's important to note that *no assignment happens here*. We are not assigning to `B`. We are constructing `B`. Code of the form:

```
T var = expr;
```

is copy-**initialization**, it is not copy-assignment. Hence, we do two things:

1. We construct a temporary `Rectangle` using the `Rectangle(int, int)` constructor
2. That temporary binds directly to the reference in the implicitly generated move (or copy, pre-C++11) constructor, which is then invoked - doing a member-wise move (or copy) from the temporary. (Or, more precisely, overload resolution selects the best `Rectangle` constructor given a prvalue of type `Rectangle`)
3. The temporary is destroyed at the statement.

If the move constructor is deleted (or, pre-C++11, the copy constructor is marked `private`), then trying to construct `B` in this way is ill-formed. If the special member functions are left alone (as they are in this example), the two declarations of `A` of `B` will certainly compile to the same code.

---

The form of initialization in `B` may look more familiar if you actually drop the type:

```
auto B = Rectangle(3,4);
```

This is the so-called AAA (Almost Always Auto) style of declarations that Herb Sutter is a fan of. This does exactly the same thing as `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3, 4)`, just with the leading step of first deducing the type of `B` as `Rectangle`.

Comment: _"Rectangle A(3, 4); always simply invokes the Rectangle(int, int) constructor, throughout all of the history of C++ having constructors. Simple. Boring."_ Well, no, it does more than that.

Comment: _"In the newest (as of this writing) edition of the standard"_ C++17 doesn't exist yet. C++14 is the newest (as of this writing) edition of the standard.

Comment: _"that a compiler may optimize away (and by may, I mean it will certainly, unless you tell it not to)"_ Yeahhhhh but there are still "visible effects" such as requiring that the copy/move ctor is accessible.

Comment: _"We construct a temporary Rectangle using the Rectangle(int, int) constructor"_ Technically accurate (as that ctor will be invoked) but misleads a bit: we never directly call a constructor, but this wording makes it sound like we do

Comment: _"The temporary is destroyed at the statement."_ at the end of*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's true that a function-style conversion is not technically a function call syntax, but do you really need to pick on that even when the words "constructor call" weren't used?  `Rectangle(3,4)` is still an expression which causes execution of a constructor; and what exactly is the distinction between "calls a constructor" and "invokes a constructor" as you yourself said, anyway?

Comment: @aschepler: Other things happen as well as invoking the constructor. It's not a "constructor call" written in the code, and this is a common enough misconception that it deserves calling out. The comments section is for critiquing and providing peer review; if you don't like that, perhaps this is not the site for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true that `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3, 4);` actually does three things in serial?

No, that isn't true, but it's not really your fault: this is confusing.

`T obj2 = obj1` is not an assignment, but an *initialisation*.

So you're right that `obj1` will be created first (in your case, a temporary), but `obj2` will be constructed using the *copy constructor*, not default constructed then assigned-to.

---

> For `Rectangle C = new Rectangle(3, 4);`, the only difference is that the memory space of the temporary variable is allocated to the heap instead of stack.

No, it won't compile, but `Rectangle* C` would. There are plenty of explanations of dynamic allocation here already.

Comment: Thanks, then is `Rectangle A(3,4)` equivalent to `Rectangle A = Rectangle(3, 4);`? If not, which one is preferred? It seems that `Rectangle A(3,4)` is more commonly used, right?

Comment: @HanfeiSun: Not quite equivalent (until C++17) but in this case functionally identical yes. And yes.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, there's a significant difference between what *actually* happens, and what theoretically sort of happens.

The first is simple: `Rectangle A(3, 4);` just constructs a Rectangle with `width` and `height` initialized to `3` and `4`. It's all done in "one step" using the `Rectangle(int, int);` constructor you defined. Simple and straightforward--so it's what's generally preferred and recommended when it's possible.

Then let's consider: `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3,4);`. In theory, this constructs a temporary object, then copy-constructs `B` from that temporary.

In practice, what happens is that the compiler checks that it *would* be able to create the temporary object, and that it would be able to use the copy constructor to initialize `B` from that temporary. Having checked that this would be possible, nearly any competent compiler (at least when optimization is enabled, and often even when it's not) will generate code essentially identical to what it did for creating `A`.

If, however, you delete the copy constructor, by adding:

```
Rectangle(Rectangle const &) = delete;
```

...then the compiler will find that it can't copy construct `B` from the temporary, and will refuse to compile the code. Even if the final, generated code never actually *uses* the copy constructor, it has to be available for this to work.

Finally, let's look at your third example (with the syntax corrected):

```
Rectangle *C = new Rectangle(3, 4);
```

Despite *looking* somewhat like the line above that created `B`, the construction involved is really much more like the previous one that you used to create `A`. Only *one* object is (even theoretically) created. It's allocated from the free store and directly initialized using your `Rectangle(int, int);` constructor.

Then the *address* of that object is used to initialize `C` (which is only a pointer). Like the initialization of `A`, this will work even if `Rectangle`'s copy constructor is deleted, because even in theory there's no copying of a `Rectangle` involved.

None of these involves an assignment operator. If you were to delete the assignment operator:

```
Rectangle &operator=(Rectangle const &) = delete;
```

...all this code would still be fine, because (despite the use of the `=`) there's no assignment anywhere in the code.

To use an assignment (if you really insisted on doing so) you could (for example) do something like:

```
Rectangle A(3, 4);
Rectangle B = Rectangle(5, 6);
B = A;
```

This still uses only constructors to create and initialize `A` and `B`, but then uses the assignment operator to assign the value of `A` to `B`. In this case, if you deleted the assignment operator as shown above, the code would fail (would not compile).

Some of our misunderstanding seems to stem from the fact that the compiler with automatically create "special member functions" for you if you don't do something to prevent it from doing so. One of the ways you can prevent it from doing so is the `= delete;` syntax shown above, but that's not the only one. For example, if your class includes a member variable of reference type, the compiler won't create an assignment operator for you. If you start with something simple like this:

```
struct Rectangle { 
    int width, height;
};
```

...the compiler will generate a default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment and move assignment operators, all entirely automatically.

Answer (score -3):

1. `Rectangle* C = new Rectangle(3,4);`, there's grammar error in your code.
2. `operator =(Rectangle& rho)` is by-default defined returning reference. Thus, `Rectangle B = Rectangle(3, 4);` won't create `tmp` object as you described above.

Comment: 1. That's not a grammar error. 2. `operator=` has nothing to do with it

Comment: the post said `Rectangle C = new Rectangle(3,4);` I DO know this is wrong.

Comment: I wrote a class with `operator=` printing message, the result shows your comment is right. Thanks a lot.